# How to escape this command in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, pg-dump

I want to generate dynamically a set of switches for `PG_DUMP` like below:

```bat
--table=mySchema.foo --table=mySchema.bar ...
```

However, I want to restrict those switches to views only. The views names don't follow a pattern. They all reside in a single schema called `mySchema`.

Here is the batch file script I wrote:

```bat
@echo off

set PARAM_HOTE=localhost

set PARAM_PORT=5435

set PSQL="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\psql.exe"

set SQL_QUERY=^
select string_agg( '--table=' || quote_ident(nspname) || '.' || quote_ident(relname), ' ' )^
  from (^
      select *^
        from pg_class^
        join pg_namespace on pg_namespace.oid = pg_class.relnamespace^
       where relkind = 'v'^
         and nspname = 'mySchema'^
    order by relname ASC^
  ) infos_vues^
;

for /f %%i in ('"%PSQL%" --quiet --tuples-only --host %PARAM_HOTE% --port %PARAM_PORT% --username "rec" -c "%SQL_QUERY%" db') do set PG_DUMP_SWITCHES_FOR_VIEWS_ONLY=%%i

:: Call PG_DUMP...
```

When I run it, I am getting the following error:

> `'"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\psql.exe"" -c "select'` is not recognized as an internal 
>       or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: too much quotes. Better use this syntax for setting variables: `set "var=value"` (the quotes should NOT be part of the value)

Comment: @Stephan I used the quotes in order to preserve readability.

Comment: Wow! Two high-rated users with the same name! This is somewhat confusing...  **`;)`**

Comment: Stephan OP: what @Stephan answerer said is that you should write it this way: `set "PSQL=C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\psql.exe"`; otherwise the quotes are _assigned_ to the variable value, **OR** remove the quotes when you use the `%PSQL%` variable...

Comment: @Aacini: yes, it's a bit confusing to talk to oneself... :D

Comment: There are so many single-quotes (or apostrophies, `'`), so I believe `for /F` might get confused; better use `for /F "usebackq" %%i in (\`...\`) do ...` (together with the changed quotation of the `set` command lines)

Comment: Why wouldn't you just put the query into a script file and have the SQL command read the query from the file?

Comment: @Squashman I want to keep everything in one single file.

Comment: @Aacini According to SO, as of today Stephan answerer and I are the only "Stephan"s with rep greater than 25k.

Comment: @Stephan You comment said: *"the quotes should NOT be part of the value"* why ?

Comment: @Stephan it's bad coding practice. Just look how you quoted it with the `set` command and quoted the already quoted value again with the `for` loop (which could cause big trouble (well, not with that special value, but there may be poisonous characters, which are secured with quoting.)). Think of `echo hello&world` - would give you an error. `echo "hello&world"` works fine, but `echo ""hello&world""` gives error again, because the `&` is "out of quoting" again. Quote it where it needs to be quoted. That keeps your code readable and predictable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved my issue:

```bat
@echo off

set PARAM_HOTE=localhost

set PARAM_PORT=5435

set PSQL="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin\psql.exe"

set SQL_LISTE_VUES=^
select string_agg( concat('--table=' , quote_ident(nspname) , '.' , quote_ident(relname)), ' ' )^
  from (^
      select *^
        from pg_class^
        join pg_namespace on pg_namespace.oid = pg_class.relnamespace^
       where relkind = 'v'^
         and nspname = 'rec'^
    order by relname ASC^
  ) infos_vues^
;

for /f  "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`%%PSQL%% --quiet --tuples-only --host %PARAM_HOTE% --port %PARAM_PORT% --username "rec" -c "%SQL_LISTE_VUES%" REC`) do set LISTE_VUES=%%i
echo %LISTE_VUES%
```

- I rewrote my query by replacing `||` with the `concat` function
- I used back ticks
- I escaped `%` with `%%` in the `for` command

Comment: `||` could also have been escaped like `^>^>`. I still recommend using `set "PSQL=..."` (also for other `set` assignments) and later `"%PSQL%"`; the `%%` just lets the variable expand later here, but that is not necessary with proper quotation... +1 anyway for finding the solution on your own...

Comment: You were given a couple of really bullet proof best practices for batch files in several comments. I would advise you use them.

Comment: @aschipfl Using the syntax `set "PSQL=..."` brings this error `'"C:\Program ' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`. I may replace `Program Files` with `Progra~1` but this notation is a bit cryptic.

Comment: Hm... seemse to be caused by the quotation handling of `cmd`... this could be resolved by adding a pair of escaped quotes: `for /F ... %%i in (\`^""%PSQL%" --quiet ... REC^"\`) do ...`

Comment: @aschipfl Now it works but the syntax isn't much intuitive.

Comment: Yes, I agree; `for /F` actually starts a `cmd` instance with the given command line, using `cmd /C`; when you type `cmd /?` you'll find a description of the complicated quotation handling of `cmd`, which is the problem here as the very first and last quotation marks become unfortunately removed here; the (escaped) additional quotes are put there for `cmd` to have something to remove...